# Managing multiple sockets in a network client in Python

Tags: python, python-2.x, socket

I'm writing a small [FIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Financial_Information_eXchange) client in Python (2.7, constraint I cannot waive for now, unfortunately).

There will be multiple sockets, connecting to different ports, so I thought I'd create a `SocketManager` to keep a list of sockets and have `select.epoll` `register()` them all.

Each socket is wrapped by a `ThinSocketWrapper` class, which basically adds a lock, two string buffers (to receive and send) and a Queue (to receive messages):

```
class ThinSocketWrapper(socket):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.BUFLEN = 4096
        self.lock = RLock()

        self.recvBuffer = ''
        self.sendBuffer = ''

        self.recvQueue = kwargs.pop('recvQueue')
        super(ThinSocketWrapper, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Questions:

1. The queue is created by the caller and passed in as an argument. This seems a bit messy to me. Would it be better to create the queue from within this class and make it accessible (e.g. through a `getRecvQueue` method)?
2. The same way I could create a `sendQueue` in `ThinSocketWrapper` and make it accessible through `getSendQueue()`. The purpose of this queue is that it will be swept by a background thread looking for messages to send. Where should this thread live? Within the `ThinSocketWrapper` class? Are there better ways of sweeping a queue? Like a `select.epoll` for queues?

   The `SocketManager` is basically a thread, whose main loop looks like this:

   ```
   class SocketManager(Thread):

       def run(self):
           while True:
               try:
                   events = self.epoll.poll(TIMEOUT)
               except IOError as e:
                   if e.errno == errno.EINTR:
                       continue

               for socket, event in events:
                   try:
                       if event & (select.EPOLLIN | select.EPOLLPRI):
                           self.readEvent(socket)
                       elif event & select.EPOLLOUT:
                           self.writeEvent(socket)
                       elif event & (select.EPOLLHUP | select.EPOLLERR):
                           self.unregister(socket)
                   except:
                       socket.close()
                       self.unregister(socket)
   ```

   `readEvent` is defined as follows:

   ```
       def readEvent(self, socket):
           try:
               while True:
                   data = socket.recv(socket.BUFLEN)
                   if not data:
                       raise RuntimeError('Socket closed (read)')
                   socket.recvBuffer += data
           except socket.error as e:
               if e.errno != errno.EAGAIN:
                   raise
               socket.recvQueue.append(socket.recvBuffer)
               socket.recvBuffer = ''
   ```
3. At the end, when we're done receiving, we basically convert whatever we received in pseudo-messages, that is we copy everything in `recvBuffer` to `recvQueue`. I say "pseudo" because it might well be that the endpoint sends us multiple messages back to back, which would be impossible to split unless we look at the content: in that situation, we would end up with multiple messages in the same item of the queue.

   This tells me that packing what has been received into messages is not this class' responsibility (in fact it should be a layer higher, from the point of view of the networking stack). What would be a nicer alternative?